# How to implement simple average moving as window function

Tags: postgresql

I want to implement simple average moving algorithm rolling along time series data. I think the best practice to do it is the implementation of a window function with the range of average moving window size as parameter.

I have browsed some materials, but there is little introduction to customized window function. Can someone point the direction how can I implement my own window function? for example simple moving average

Comment: What's wrong with `avg(x) over (order by y)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  1) the window size can not be given as parameter? 2) not adaptable to weighted moving average

Comment: Well, you didn't mention weighted moving averages in the question. And the window size *can* be specified; `ROWS n PRECEDING ...` etc. See the manual for details. Anyway, for writing window functions your best resource is the source code for existing window functions.